# Migrated XAMPP to GAE LAMP Users Cannot Log In

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, lamp

I have migrated my developement app from my local machine running XAMPP to the Google App Engine with Bitnami on LAMP. Everything has run smoothly and even accessing the database name in the server returns the same `0` to demonstrate that it is working:

[image]

However, in updating this information within my android mobile application and attempting to allow a user to log in, the background service is not able to make a connection to the server and refuses the user to authenticate and log in.

This is the first time I have attempted deploying a server to the Google App Engine.

Is there a way to debug this issue to see what the server is doing? Is there a configuration that would work?

Comment: there are logs that you can view

Comment: But why would the xampp server allow the messages to be sent and parsed, but in GAE on LAMP  it notes junk? They are the exact same configuration..